# Regaining Preview on Safari without uninstalling Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, safari, adobe-reader, safari-extensions

Certain institutions will only let you fill online forms with the Adobe Reader installed on your browser. My questions is, is there any way of disabling it in Safari without having to uninstall it? It's pretty annoying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link says it should be fairly simple... Just move or delete a file...

> First, close Safari and launch Finder. Press Command-Shift-G (or choose Go > Go to Folder from Finder’s menu bar) to open the Go to Folder window. Enter the following location and press Return:
>
> /Library/Internet Plug-ins/
>
> OS X Finder Internet Plugins Library
>
> The contents of this folder will vary depending on the number and type of your Safari plug-ins, but look for the files called AdobePDFViewer.plugin and AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin (note that depending on your version of Acrobat, you may only have the first file).
>
> OS X Safari Acrobat PDF Plugins
>
> You now have a choice: if you hate the Acrobat Safari plug-in and want to return to the OS X default PDF viewer forever, simply delete both files above. If, however, you’d like to preserve the option to go back to the Acrobat Safari plug-in in the future, move both files out of the Internet Plug-ins folder and back them up in a new folder elsewhere (your user Documents folder, for example).

http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/disable-acrobat-safari-plugin/

Comment: Solved the issue, works as you described. Thanks!